# With Pyramid - How to get the host_url with the mount point?

Tags: python, pyramid, mount-point

I have a pyramid application that I am mounting with MOD-WSGI in /myApp however request.host_url() returns the host URL without the mount point. For now I am fixing this by having the mount point in a variable in the INI file  that I concatenate later on to request.host_url() but is there a better way to get the host_url with the mount point?

Comment: Did you find the [Pyramid mod_wsgi tutorial](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html), specifically Step 8, not helpful?

Comment: It is helpful to know how to mount your application using WSGI however, using the same tutorial if you call request.host_url() you get the host URL but WITHOUT the mount point (/myApp). So the question is how to get the host URL WITH the mount point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

presumably you aren't properly setting `WSGIScriptAlias /mountpoint /path/to/my/foo.wsgi` as defined https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIScriptAlias.html - if this is done then mod_wsgi should be setting the `request.script_name` in your environ properly which will affect the `request.host_url` value.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This pointed me to the solution: host_url returns the URL through the host (no path) while application_url returns the URL through the host + SCRIPT_NAME (no PATH_INFO or query string).